# "Callback" after Angular *ngIf

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, angular-ng-if

I'm new to Angular and it's concepts, and i'm trying to wrap my head around how to deal with this particular scenario.

I'm using events from Cordova's Keyboard plugin to set a `keyboardVisible` property in my page component, and using it to show/hide the footer.

```
<ion-footer *ngIf="!keyboardVisible">
    <ion-text>Footer content</ion-text>
</ion-footer>
```

The footer is hidden/shown correctly, but I need to call `resize()` on the underlying `Content` in the component to update the layout ([as is mentioned here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/content/Content/#resizing-the-content))...

```
@ViewChild(Content) content: Content;
this.content.resize();
```

... and I can't for the life of me figure out how/where to call this after the `*ngIf` directive has done it's thing.

Answer (score 1):

If resize doesn't return anything you can simply do this

```
<ion-footer *ngIf="!keyboardVisible">
    {{content.resize()}}
    <ion-text>Footer content</ion-text>
</ion-footer>
```

Comment: Trouble is I need to call the resize event after the keyboard is both opened and closed, (so when `keyboardVisible == true` and `keyboardVisible == false`). I don't this would work here as it would only be called when it's closed.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ion-footer *ngIf="check(!keyboardVisible)"">
<ion-text>Footer content</ion-text>
</ion-footer>

export class YourCom{

   check(item){
       if(!keyboardVisible){
          this.content.resize();
       }

   }
}
```

just to give you a heads up that if you call a function that updates the view somehow, you're gonna get an error from change detection that says >"Expression updated after view is checked"

Comment: Thanks, but the `content.resize` method is build into Ionic and is as far as I can see is the recommended way of refreshing the view layout after something's modified it.